# Regarding concurrent modification Exception

Tags: java, multithreading

Could you please tell is there any way in which concurrent modification exception could occur in a single threaded environment also the below application which I am posting consists of two threads , please tell me can I see the same exception in a single thread also..please advise

```
package concurrentmodificationError;

import java.util.*;

class ItrDemo
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
       Vector v=new Vector();
       v.addElement("Amit");
       v.add("Rahul");
       v.add(1,"Nitin");
       v.addElement("Ankit");
       System.out.println("There are "+v.size()+"elements in the vector ");

       final Iterator itr=v.iterator();
       Thread th=new Thread()    {
               public void run()
               {
                   System.out.println("New Thread started,traversing     elements of vector...");
                   System.out.println("Contents of vector are...");
                   while(itr.hasNext())
                   {
                     System.out.println(itr.next());
                     try
                      {
                          Thread.sleep(2000);
                       }
                      catch(Exception e1)
                      {
                      }
                   }
              }
         };// end of annomyous class
      System.out.println("Suspending main thread and starting a new thread       for traversing the contents of vector...");
      th.start();
      try
       {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       }
       catch(Exception e1)
       {
       }
       System.out.println("main thread resumed,modifying vector...");
       v.remove("Ankit");
       v.add("Puneet");
       v.add("Raman");
       System.out.println("Vector Modified , Ankit removed and Puneet &        Raman added.");
  }

}
```

yeah I got it folks that in the single threaded enviorement this error can comes.. as shown in below piece of code..

```
System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
          ListIterator itr1=list.listIterator();
          while(itr1.hasNext())
          {
              list.add(new Emp("Anand","Manager",56000)); //
            Emp e=(Emp)itr1.next();  
            e.display();
          }
```

Please advise what are the ways to overcome it..so that does not get this error..!!Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` can be thrown in a single thread environment. It is used whenever an object is modified in a context where it shouldn't, not necessarily in another thread.

Example:

```
public class CME {
    public static void main(String...args) {
        HashSet<Integer> coll = new HashSet<Integer>();
        coll.add(1);
        coll.add(2);
        coll.add(3);

        for(Integer i : coll) {
            coll.remove(i); // Throws ConcurrentModificationException
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the the Javadoc of [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html),

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has
>   been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread
>   issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of
>   an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a
>   thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the
>   collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will thow this
>   exception.

Its not always that this exception would be thrown when a thread-safe collection is subject to concurrent access. Any **structural modification** (add/delete) will prompt this exception to occur.

In your particular example, **you are modifying the collection outside of Iterator** and hence it might throw this exception once the thread wakes up from sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to get this exception (not error) also in a single-threaded environment. 
More precisely the exception is thrown whenever a collection you're currently iterating through is modified either by another thread or by the current thread.

An example of a single-threaded scenario in which you get this error is the following:

```
Iterator<String> names = namesList.iterator();
while(names.hasNext()){
    String currentName = names.next();
    if(currentName.startsWith("A")){
           namesList.remove(currentName); //here you modify the original collection
    }
}
```

In this case, if the iterator is a fail-fast iterator (as most of the collection implementations provide) you will get a ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown even in a single thread, if a collection is modified while iterating.
e.g.

```
        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("sample");

        for(String str : lst) {
            lst.add("simple");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic example of a CME in a single thread is something like

```
List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>();
strs.add("foo");
strs.add("bar");

for(String str : strs) {
  strs.add(str + " added");
}
```

The CME fires because you're in the process of iterating over the list and you modify it *other than via the iterator*.  You *are* allowed to modify the list via its iterator without getting a CME:

```
ListIterator<String> strIt = strs.listIterator();
while(strIt.hasNext()) {
  String str = strIt.next();
  strIt.add(str + " added");
}
// strs now contains "foo", "foo added", "bar", "bar added"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems (to me) to a little bit cryptic...

Regarding your first question, getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` in a single threaded environment, all you need to do  would be something like so:

```
List<String> list =...;
for (String str : list)
{
    list.remove(str); //this should yield the exception
}
```

As to your second question, that code you have posted (the one with 2 threads) will most likely be prone to such an Exception. So far it is working due the amount of items you have and also the time out value. Should you change these, you will most likely experience this exception.

To avoid this, you could use [`synchronized blocks`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html). By allowing each thread a synchronized section through which it can do it's collection modifications you should be able to steer clear from concurrent modification exceptions.

You could also regulate access to the list through the use of a [`Semaphore`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29).