# Regarding getting error in retrieving the list

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regarding concurrent modification Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828639/regarding-concurrent-modification-exception)

I am getting this concurrent modification exception error in the below code as I am trying to remove the elements while iterating ..the code is below..

```
 List  list=new ArrayList ();
          list.add(new Emp("Saral","Trainer",34500));
          list.add(new Emp("Saral","Trainer",36000));
          list.add(new Emp("Saral","Trainer",33000));
          list.add(new Emp("Sachin","Programmer",24000));
```

and the way I am retrieving is ..

```
System.out.println("Content of list are : ");
          ListIterator itr1=list.listIterator();
          while(itr1.hasNext())
          {
              list.add(new Emp("Anand","Manager",56000)); //
            Emp e=(Emp)itr1.next();  
            e.display();
          }
```

Could you please advise how this error can be avoided..?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to modify a `List` and use an `Iterator` that was created prior to the modification of `List` from which the `List` was obtained, otherwise a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown. To avoid, don't call `list.add()` inside the `while`.

As the purpose of the offending `while` is to print the content of the list, there is no reason to use an `Iterator`:

```
List<Emp> list = new ArrayList<Emp>();  

for (Emp e: list)
{
    e.display();
}
```

Comment: Even if it was possible, adding to the list while iterating through it would result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify the list while iterating which may result in `ConcurrentModificationExceptio`n

```
list.add(new Emp("Anand","Manager",56000)); //
```

Comment: @thinksteep..yeah I know that , the point is that how can I avoid it

Comment: @user1579492: You can avoid it by not modifying the list while iterating through it (you are adding to the list, which is modifying it)

Comment: You may need to use something like copyonWriteArrayList http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html.